# QGIS - Lakes - Change Polygon Z values, using Single Field Value

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, elevation

I want to change all the elevation of the polygons of a shapefile using the field value ELEV from each polygon. So each vertex of each polygons as all the same Z (elevation). Anyone knows how to do that?

Please

Steeve

Comment: Where is the ELEV field stored?

Comment: ... in the attribute table, and each Lakes has an elevation field, which i try to use for actual elevation for each polygon. It is already a 3D polygon. I tried v.extrude and v.to.3d already, but couldnt get the result I wanted...

Comment: If you are using `v.to.3d` in QGIS2.18, try (1) NOT to use a 3D polygon as the input. You need original 2D polygon with Z attribute field. (2) In `Advanced parameters` select **area** in `v.out.ogr output type` pull-down menu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In QGIS 3.0, run the "set z value" algorithm. Hit the button next to z value and select the field containing your desired z values.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wasnt aware of version 3. I really appreciate.